# Using setTimeout in JS loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change the source of an image every 5 second  loading from and array of arrays called `imgs` ,but I am getting this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '3' of undefined

at

```
$("#map_image").attr("src", path+ imgs[i][j]);
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
let i;
let j;
for (i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < imgs[i].length; j++) { 
          (function(index) {
            setTimeout(function() { 
                $("#map_image").attr("src", path+ imgs[i][j]);
            }, i * 5000);
    })(i);
    }
```

Comment: The infamous for loop

Comment: I already saw this post and that's why I used the `ES6 solution: let` but still having the issue

Comment: for (let i = 0;..... for(let j=0;.....

Comment: I did changed and now I am getting all images in array when trying `console.log(imgs[i][j]);`